# Web Share API - Using NFC to share a URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nfc

I'm using [Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) to try and share a URL via NFC.

```
navigator.share({
  title: document.title,
  text: 'Hello World',
  url: 'https://developer.mozilla.org',
});
```

It works for every app besides Android Beam (NFC). Anyone have any luck with sharing URLs using NFC via a web app?